# iOS Development: Can I store an array of integers in a Core Data object without creating a new table to represent the array?

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-data, ios

I'm using Core Data and I'm trying to figure out the simplest way to store an array of integers in one of my Core Data entities.  Currently, my entities contain various arrays of objects that are more complex than a single number, so it makes sense to represent those arrays as tables in my DB and attach them using relationships.  If I want to store a simple array of integers, do I need to create a new table with a single column and attach it using a one-to-many relationship?  Or is there a more simple way?

Thanks in advance for your wisdom!

Comment: (Added an answer suggesting an inefficient option of converting the array into a string via `componentsJoinedByString` and separating them back out later via `componentsSeparatedByString`, but afterward realized that the first conversion would require converting each integer into an NSNumber first since integers don't have `description`s, and you'd have to convert the array of NSStrings into integers when pulling them back out. Likely way too much overhead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Chris Hanson](http://www.mail-archive.com/cocoa-dev@lists.apple.com/msg31711.html) already gave a good answer to this question, still if you really want to store the NSArray as Core Data attribute take a look at [transformable attributes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdNSAttributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001919)

Comment: I don't think Chris Hanson gave an answer to this question.  What Chris Hanson describes doesn't really apply to the situation where you just have an array of integers that you don't need to do any searching on.  Say the integers are actually enums.  Should I really have a table that repeats the same enum over and over again because it is referenced from many other objects?

Answer (score 1):

For an array of integers, I would use a Binary property - which is an NSData. NSData has a lot of accessor/modifier methods. If you need/want to keep an mutable copy, then you can use NSMutableData as a cache - and persist that (as an NSData) as makes sense.

I use this for long lists of doubles - which, for me, represent collected data sets. This works for me because I have no need to link a single data point to some other object in my model. At runtime, I unpack these data sets and use them to render graph lines. At that point, I could generate some sort of relatedness - but that relatedness would need to be derived.